# Python- Reading from multiple text files into dictionary

Tags: python, text, dictionary

I'm trying to combine two files into a dictionary. They are both text files.

The first file has the state initials and population. It looks like this:

```
AL 4447100
AK 626932
AZ 5130632
AR 2673400
CA 33871648
CO 4301261
...
```

The second file has the state initial and state name (this time per line, not side by side):

```
AL
Alabama
AK
Alaska
AZ
Arizona
AR
Arkansas
CA
California
CO
Colorado
...
```

I'm trying to create a dictionary that looks like this

```
{'Alabama': 4447100, 'Alaska': 626932, ...}
```

Now, I'm having trouble reading the first text file. How do I read just the numbers when the abbreviations are in the way?

The second text file is easier as I can read every other line.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to read just the numbers, and just the full state names? Don't you need to link the abbreviations in one file to those in the other?

Comment: @jamylak No, this is not HW, im trying to create a info-graphic based on this. This is just the start.

Comment: @Marius, yes, I just want the numbers and full state names. They are in the same order in both files, so I can easily match them up without using the abbreviations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) depending on how you've read the data in.

For example:

```
>>> myStr = 'AL 4447100'
>>> myStr.split(' ')
>>> ['AL', '447100']
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't give a full solution since this may be homework but your final one should have some code like this

```
d = {}

with open('file1.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
         state, pop = line.split()
         d[states[state]] = int(pop) # states is a dictionary with initials as 
                                     # the  keys and full names as values
```

Answer (score 0):

Q) Now, I'm having trouble reading the first text file. How do I read just the numbers when the abbreviations are in the way?

A) You can use this with a string of each line to strip the first 3 characters from the string (acronym and a space):

```
number = lineString[3:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have files `states.txt` and `pop.txt`

```
with open("states.txt") as f1:
   x= f1.read().split()
   states = {state:abrv for state,abrv in zip(x[0::2],x[1::2])}

with open("pop.txt") as f2:
   y= f2.read().split()
   pop = {states[abrv]:val for abrv,val in zip(y[0::2],y[1::2])}
```